# php mail() function strips off special characters on the subject

Tags: php, email, special-characters

this is the code I have:

```
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
    $msg = "1'2 ’3"4 “5”6 7~8!9@10#11$12%13^14&15*16(17)18}19{20"21:22?23>24<25 ";
    $subject = "1'2 ’3"4 “5”6 7~8!9@10#11$12%13^14&15*16(17)18}19{20"21:22?23>24<25;
    mail("myemail@example.com",$subject,$msg);
```

the message comes complete, but the subject only shows

> 1'2 ’3

the subject comes from row['subject'] on the db.
any ideas please?

Answer (score 1):

Try escaping the double quotes:

```
"1'2 ’3\"4 \“5\”6 7~8!9@10#11$12%13^14&15*16(17)18}19{20\"21:22?23>24<25 ";
```

Comment: I thought about that but it comes from the database ?

Comment: All you should need to do is pass the output of the database into a call to `str_replace`, and use the output of that as the subject.

Comment: If you don't want to do ao str_replace, also try `addslashes`.